# Determine whether an array contains duplicate values

Tags: c#, algorithm, programming-challenge

My solution for the leet code problem to search an array of ints for duplicate values and return a boolean seems quite efficient (< 90% of submissions runtime). However, I am currently reviewing Data Structures and Algorithms and I wonder if there is a more efficient approach to this, since if my counting is correct my solution will run at O(n) for worst case scenarios.  I am still new to C# (I mostly code in js).

```
public bool ContainsDuplicate(int[] nums) {
        HashSet<int> singles = new HashSet<int>();
            for(int i = 0; i < nums.Length;i++)
            {
                if (singles.Contains(nums[i]))
                    return true;
                singles.Add(nums[i]);
                
            }
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure it's `O(n)` ? because the `Contains` has an iterator as well which puts it `O(n^2)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20507592/648075 (note that this is for an older version of .NET, more recent versions might have implemented this differently.)

Comment: @BCdotWEB I just checked it here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,188b8f94f8fc999b (it's still valid on 4.8 .NET) have not validate it on .NET Core yet.

Comment: I think your counting is incorrect, because set containment is usually O(log _n_), and I don't see how C# can outperform that.

Comment: From a clean code perspective GroupBy is probably the best approach

Comment: @iSR5 ah i was unaware of this, I am still very new to C# only been really learning it for about a month. Thank you for that!

Comment: If you're going to continue with C#, learning LINQ can unlock a whole new world. LINQ can do this pretty efficiently code-wise (would have to research BIG O) with something like: `myArray.GroupBy(i => i).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be slightly optimized by not using `Contains()` but checking the returned value from `Add()`. If the item is allready contained in the `HashSet<T>` calling `Add()` will return `false`.

```
public bool ContainsDuplicate(int[] nums) {
    HashSet<int> singles = new HashSet<int>();
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.Length;i++)
    {
        if (!singles.Add(nums[i]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How about a one liner: `return new HashSet<int>(nums).Count < nums.Length` ?

Comment: This would add all items first where in my answer it would return at the first duplicate.

Comment: ah I like this thank you!

Comment: @Heslacher yes.